# SQL Server: Stored procedure to delete an existing account

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

If a user wants to delete his/her account, while in session, I guess that you need to enter your password again to verify identity just in case. Here is my SQL code:

```
CREATE PROC spDeleteAccount @Password nvarchar(100) -- I'm expecting a password input to verify identity again
AS
BEGIN
  IF (@Password IS NOT NULL) -- If user exists
  BEGIN
    DELETE FROM tblUsers
    WHERE Password = @Password

    SELECT 1 AS ReturnCode
  END

  ELSE -- If user doesn't exist
  BEGIN
    SELECT 0 AS ReturnCode
  END
END
```

Is this the right way to do it?

For the ASP part: What happens with the session in ASP.NET? Does it become null?

Comment: Is it right way? No because password verification isn't something you want to do in database...

Comment: It's also the wrong way because passwords should not be unique.

Comment: This stored proc will delete all the users who have specific password. Also from the stored proc it is clear that you are storing password in plain text which is a big security hole.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya No, passwords are encrypted and in the Password input case, I also encrypt it in c# before sending it to the DB. But I get your point about the first sentence, I shall add the email attribute aswell

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked about the right (I would say common) way I suggest you the following :

Don't do any attempt on deleting an account specially when the user is logged-in but ask for their confirmation to de-activate it. When you get the confirmation then deactivate the account so that's for the common strategy.

**Now what, Lets say 1000 users of your system have deactivated? What should happen next?**

Have a service or a Query job in place that after certain days of deactivation it will perform the actual deletion of the account.

**How to delete an ASP.NET user?**

This is fairly broad and depending on the structure of your system, different queries are required but if you insist on deleting the user then you should delete all related child tables records then delete the record itself.

Consider using [ASP.NET Identity](https://www.asp.net/identity) so you wont reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I'll keep these in mind to implement